# What are alternatives of Visual Statistics in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, software, interactive-visualization

There is software, "[Visual Statistics](https://www.visualstats.org/)", which helps to visualize some concepts in Statistics. For example, if I want to teach confidence interval at confidence level %95, I would say if I replicate the experiment 100 times, on average, 95 of them will contain the true mean. This software helps up to simulate this process. It is possible to do similar simulations for other concepts. I am wondering if there is any other software or any package in R for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/) containing a large number of examples of graphs produced in `R`.  Virtually any statistical graph can be replicated in this language with sufficient expertise, though there is a learning curve involved.  Most of the best graphics produced in `R` come from the `ggplot2` package; you can find an introduction to using the package [here](https://ggplot2-book.org/introduction.html).